# Problem with C# application and dll unable to register

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reference, plc, dllregistration

I've done a C# application with Microsoft VisualStudio professional 2019 to communicate with ControlLogix processor using Libplctagwrapper namespace.
In developer system with Windows 10 pro 64-bit O.S. I don't have any problem running the application.
I had a problem registering plctag.dll in the target system with a virtual machine developed using Hyper-V console and O.S. Windows 10 Pro 64 bit.
I tried to register with regsvr32 command in admin privilegies cmd prompt console, but I received the error of unable to load plctag.dll module.
I tried in system32 and syswow64 both directory and received everytime the error of unable to load dll module.
I'm waiting to receive help information.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the startup project of your program.
Open the properties window.
Click the compile tab.
Click advanced compile options.
Change the target CPU options to x86.
Rebuild and Upload

Edit: VS2019
Build Platform target to x86